# Neptune `barrier()` optimization

Tags: amazon-neptune

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-traversal-tuning.html

This documentation mentions an important optimization affecting Neptune engine version 1.0.5.0 recommending a `barrier()` step during a specific traversal sequence:

```
g.V().hasLabel('airport').
  order().
    by(out().count(),desc).
  limit(10).
  out()
```

Does this strictly apply only to the `order().by().limit()` sequence, or would it also affect `order().by().range()`?

Would placing `barrier()` as the very last step of the traversal suffice, or does it need to come directly after `limit()`?

If the traversal contains multiple `order().by().limit()` sequences, would a single `barrier()` suffice, or does each instance need it's own `barrier()`? Note that I'm using these within `project(...).by(__.order().by().limit()).by(__.order().by().limit())`.

Comment: Hello. This change affects any order step. Placing a single barrier anywhere in the query, such as at the very end as you suggest, should be sufficient. Are you able to post a concrete example of the way you use `project` with `order`? That will help me verify the answer applies there as well.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Here is an example `g.V()
.hasLabel("user")
.order()
.by("postStreakRecord", order.desc)
.by(
  __.out("post")
    .order()
    .by("createdDate", order.desc)
    .limit(1)
    .values("createdDate"),
  order.desc
)
.by("postCount", order.desc)
.by("createdDate", order.asc);`

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Here is an example that uses nested `project` and `order` from my code. `g.V().hasLabel("alert").order().by("createdDate").limit(10).project("id", "users").by(__.id()).by(
__.out("alert").hasLabel("user").order().by("createdDate").limit(10).project("id").by(__.id())
)`. Would a single `barrier()` at the end be enough?